# How can I open modules defined outside my project root directory in my ocaml file?

Tags: ocaml, oasis

I'm not experienced in ocaml, my situation here is that I'm writing my ocaml code, I try to access the types that defined in other .ml files, which locate outside of my project root directory. 
I tried to set up _oasis, however when I specify the ***library*** field, the ***Path*** value is invalid as I try to use **"../../dir"**. 
Does anyone know how can I achieve this goal? I don't want to copy them into my project root directory, as I was looking through those tutorials, haven't found a solution yet, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea of oasis is that you have one `_oasis` file in the root directory of your project, and that file defines the whole project. Hence, all the paths are specified relative to the root folder (the one that contains `_oasis`)

In your case, the project structure could look like this:

```
my_project/
|
+- _oasis
+-lib/
| |
| +- types/
|    |
|    +- common.ml
+-src/
  |
  +- app/
     |
     +- app_main.ml
```

And an `_oasis` file that corresponds to it would be:

```
OASISFormat: 0.4
Name:        myproject
Version:     0.1
Synopsis:    captures the world
Authors:     robots
Maintainers: humans
License:     MIT
Copyrights:  (C) Acme corp
Plugins:     META (0.4)
BuildTools: ocamlbuild


Library "common_types"
  Path: lib/types
  FindlibName: acme-common-types
  Modules: Common

Executable "control-people"
  Path: src/app
  MainIs: app_main.ml
  Install: true
  BuildDepends: common_types
```

Finally, since merlin now is a tool de facto, you shall also consider teaching him your project structure, by adding the `.merlin` file to the root folder of your project with the following contents:

```
 B _build/
 B _build/lib/types
 B _build/src/app
 S lib/types
 S src/app
```

If you have any external dependencies, you can add them to `.merlin` using `PKG <findlib-name-of-the-dep>`, e.g., `PKG core_kernel`. And, of course, you should add your external dependencies to you libraries and applications in the _oasis file, by using the `BuildDepends` clause, e.g., `BuildDepends: core_kernel`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer is pretty clear to me! How can I module `path` in `.merlin` file though? Assum the `common.ml` is outside my project root, i.e. `../main/srce/`, how can specify the `Common` module path in .merlin?

Comment: just add corresponding paths to the build (`B`) and source `S` folders, the path is relative to the `.merlin` path, so you can even escape your project boundaries and reference to other libraries/projects